# Python programming, syntax error for game

Tags: python, syntax

```
#makes a varible called name to identify the players name
name=input("Hello person, Whats your name?")
#prints their name
print("Hello", name)
#console asks the player if they want to play the game, if choice is "yes" then continue,   else say "ok bye bye" (at the bottom!!)
print("Do you want to hear a story?", name)
choice=input("Yes, No?")
if choice==("yes" or "yes " or "Yes" or "Yes "):
    print("Ok", name,", listen up")    
    print("There was once an old, old house at the top of a hill Sooooo high it was above the clouds")
    housename=input("What do you want to call the house?")
    print("The old,",housename,"was once owned by an old lady. You decide to go up to   the", housename, ",you encounter a ghost in your path. You see a varitety of weapons beside  you, an axe, sword and a bow.")
#asks the player if they want an axe sword or bow    
    choice3=input("Do you choose the axe, sword or bow?")
#if the choice is "bow" then proceed with this code    
    if choice3==("bow" or "Bow" or "bow " or "Bow "):
        print("You equip the shoddy Bow, The bow feels as if it could snap any second.")
#sets the enemyshealth as 10
        enemyhealth=int(10)
#makes a while loop to keep the battle going instead of 1 time.
        while enemyhealth >= 1:
            print("Take a shot!")
            bowattack=input("Type attack to fire an arrow!")
            if bowattack==("attack"):
                import random
#randomiser for damage generator
                damage = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
                damage2 = int(random.choice(damage))
                enemyhealth = enemyhealth - damage2
                print("The ghost took some damage. Enemys health:", enemyhealth)

            else:
                print("Are you sure you typed shoot?")
#if the enemys health gets below 1 print you killed the ghost, reward system! **this is what im having trouble with!!**
    if enemyhealth <= 1:
        print("You killed the Ghost!!")
        print("You vanquished the ghost, you now collect a new weapon!")
#confirms the reward, either gives the player a shiny bow or a double shot bow.
        import random
        reward = ["Shiny bow", "Doubleshot bow"]
#randomiser for either reward
        reward2 =(random.choice(reward)
#prints what weapon the player got
#THIS IS THE PROBLEM, ON THIS LINE
        print("You got a:", reward2)



    #pointless easteregg :D        
    elif choice==("maybe"):
        print("You found an easter egg, congrats. PS this does nothing")
#if the player typed anything other than yes say ok bye bye.
else:
    print("Ok, bye bye", name)
```

I am fully aware that the code does not yet have the other 2 if statements for the axe or sword. What i'm having trouble with is the reward generator for killing the ghost. I think its an indention error; it says syntax error for the print line.

I know this is rather alot of code to take in but i'd really appreciate it if could help me fix this; if you see anything I could make a shortcut around that would also be helpful.
Im using python 3.4.2!

Comment: The same kind of question over and over again. Maybe we should install a bot which detects "syntax error" in the title and answers with "You're missing a closing parenthesis in the previous line." :-)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the previous line:

```
reward2 =(random.choice(reward)
```

should be:

```
reward2 =(random.choice(reward))
```

Comment: Sorry, what line is it your talking about. Im pretty much a complete noob to python :(

Answer (score 1):

Also, the line `if choice==('yes' or 'yes ' or 'Yes' or 'Yes '):` wont work.

Try this:

```py
if choice.strip().lower() == 'yes':
    # whatever
```

`strip` will remove whitespaces. `lower` will put the string in lowercase

The same happens with `choice3`

Comment: You welcome... another thing, you don't need to `import random` anytime you need to call a random function. Import it at the top of your code.